# Use same image for link for each row of a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a table i have got a remove link on each row. I am trying to add same image to link. The image is added only to the first row and not to the rest of the rows. This is what i have done.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.isSelected').click(function () {

        var pdtname = $(this).attr('data-productname');

        if ($(this).prop("checked")) {

            $("#result").show();

            if ($(".isSelected:checked").length == 2) {
                $(".isSelected").not(":checked").prop("disabled",true); 
            }
            var table = $('<table></table>').addClass('tfoo').attr("data-productname", pdtname);
            var row = $('<tr></tr>').addClass('rfoo').text(pdtname);

            **var link = $("#imgLogo").wrap('<a href="javascript:void(0);"></a>').addClass('lfoo');**

            row.append(link);
            table.append(row);
            $('#result').append(table);

            $("#result .lfoo").on('click', function () {
                $('input[data-productname="' + $(this).parent().parent().parent().attr("data-productname") + '"]').prop("checked", false);
                $(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();
                 $(".isSelected").not(":checked").prop("disabled",false);
            });


        } else {
            $('table[data-productname="' + pdtname + '"]').remove();
             $(".isSelected").not(":checked").prop("disabled",false);
        }

    });
});
```

This is the line to image link `var link = $("#imgLogo").wrap('<a href="javascript:void(0);"></a>').addClass('lfoo');`

[Link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmpm/7kk2b5sp/)

Comment: `id="imgLogo"` may only appear once on the page, otherwise use `class`

Comment: Tried but did not worked.

Comment: I also did not try to comprehend your code, that's standard compliance.  Your jsFiddle doesn't seem to have the external image.

Comment: I tried to add image but dont know how to do it on jsFiddle. But without image it works

Comment: You can't upload an image, you have to refer to an external resource, such that a hosting site may provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want something like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/7kk2b5sp/1/

There are far better ways to improve this, but that's for another question.  For what you're concerned about, you want to clone the image and use `class` instead of `id`.

Changes:

- the *link* creation js
- attributes and attribute-values in the *img* html
- added some CSS

Comment: Yes this is what i wanted. It worked. Could you say the better ways please ?

Comment: There's a lot of room for optimization.  A lot of this code can be placed outside of the click event.  Really, you shouldn't be using `img` at all, and instead be using CSS and classes.  It looks like you're creating a table at each click... you shouldn't even need to create a table.  There is way too much and I haven't really analyzed it, that's just a few quick things on the surface.

Comment: Can i open a question, could you please show it this one time.